# cache in macosx

Tags: macos, intersystems-cache, intersystems

I installed cache in macos x. But i cant able to open a studio there and i cant able to see cache cube there.How do i will open it and create clasess,routines,...etc in cache in mac osx.

Comment: I think you mean Intersystems Caché ? Does it not come with any kind of documentation ?

Answer (score 2):

IS does not provide a studio for osx. you can use the terminal (called "csession") .. although it is a bit tedious at times.

all programs to control cache are in the bin folder of your cache installation.